# Broken switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

Ive been searching and staring for hours and I'm at a loss.  I have the following code that when an august date is passed through the switch (as AUG) statement it keeps returning a 0 for the value instead of an 8. The echo results are below the code block. Any ideas with what might be going wrong?  It seemed to work well for July and broke on August 1st.

```
$when=date("Y-m-d");
    $created=date("Ymd");
    $date=explode('-',$emprow->HIRE_DATE);
    echo "<br>hire date is ";print_r($date);echo "<br>";
    switch ($date[1])
    {
        case "JAN":
            $date[1]=01;
            break;
        case "FEB":
            $date[1]=02;
            break;
        case "MAR":
            $date[1]=03;
            break;
        case "APR":
            $date[1]=04;
            break;
        case "MAY":
            $date[1]=05;
            break;
        case "JUN":
            $date[1]=06;
            break;
        case "JUL":
            $date[1]=07;
            break;
        case "AUG":
            $date[1]=08;
            break;
        case "SEP":
            $date[1]=09;
            break;
        case "OCT":
            $date[1]=10;
            break;
        case "NOV":
            $date[1]=11;
            break;
        case "DEC":
        case "Dec":
            $date[1]=12;
            break;
    }
    echo "<br>hire date is ";print_r($date);echo "<br>";
    $startdate=sprintf("%04d%02d%02d",$date[2],$misc->getmonthnum($date[1]),$date[0]);
```

Which results in the following:

hire date is `Array ( [0] => 05 [1] => AUG [2] => 2013 )`

hire date is `Array ( [0] => 05 [1] => 0 [2] => 2013 )`

startdate date is 20130005

Comment: You probably want to change your assigned numbers to string, or remove the zero padded on the left, or you might run into a problem where your numbers are treated as the wrong base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified what I put in comments.

08 is a non-existant octal number. Use "08" or 8

You can pad with zeros when you're ready to output it.

Here's an illustration of what's going on in PHP with your original code:

```
$date[1]=08;
echo $date[1];
echo ' | ';
$date[1]=010;
echo $date[1];
```

output:

```
0 | 8
```

Comment: I changed the code from 08 to "08" and it worked.  Thank you kindly showing me how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

When calling your Hire Date, you use $emprow->HIRE_DATE, from what I see.

You explode such date, delimiter "-" to break it into 3 arrays, y,m,d, and then attempt parsing the 'm'. I suggest the following:

```
$date=$emprow->HIRE_DATE;
$unixtime=strtotime($date);
$newdate=date('m',$unixtime);
```

This then should give you as a result (when echoing $newdate) "08"

Answer (score 1):

TecBrat is correct. Your number (08) is being interpreted as an octal literal, and since there is no 8 digit in base 8, the number is invalid and therefore taken to be 0. To fix this, just put quotes around your numbers so they're treated as strings.

Alternatively, you could simply do something like

```
echo date_create('05-AUG-2013')->format('m'); // prints 08
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove those extra zeroes on the left (i.e change 08 to 8, 09 to 9 and so on) or turn them into strings. If a number has an extra zero on the left it is interpreted as an octal number (base 8 number system), in which the numbers 8 and 9 are invalid, breaking your code.